# Restoring Windows 7 Backup to Windows 10 machine - Backup not showing up in dialog

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-backup, windows-7-backup

I am given to understand that [restoring backed-up files from a Windows 7 computer to your Windows 10 install](https://www.pcworld.com/article/3034527/windows/restore-a-windows-7-backup-in-windows-10.html) is viable.

I have a single backup on the external drive, storing my document folders as much as anything else. The files look like they're viable.
[image: Base directory for backup drive] [image: Drilling into backup folder]

However, when I try to restore the backup, the backup point doesn't show up (maybe a similar problem to [this guy](https://superuser.com/questions/1016585/restoring-windows-7-image-backup-in-windows-10-installed-laptop)).
[image: No restore points]

I can tell windows to install from the point by selecting it on the drive, but it displays the same empty dialog.

Are there any trouble-shooting steps, or am I better off just copying those directories from my old (functioning) desktop onto the drive directly, then copy them over?

Comment: The backup system is really more for system restoration and complete image dumps.  If you have another machine with all of the files, why not use DropBox or Google Drive or just a straight up network transfer between the two computers?

Comment: You have followed the rest of the instructions in that article I presume, and clicked "browse network location", and added the folder containing the backup image to the list of backup locations?

Comment: @CDove: Largely ignorance, I suspect. That and I thought it would be faster to transfer by physically transporting the device rather than being limited to network bandwidth.

Comment: @ramhound: I navigated to the drive in question. But it gives me the dialog above showing no restore points available there.

Comment: Have you verified the permissions are correct on the backup archive?

Comment: @Ramhound: Can you tell me what I should be looking for?